# How to clear MAC bash

Tags: bash, macos

After installing lots of gems and exporting path in my OS 10 bash appears to be messy and show lots of error. How do I clear these error.
[image]

how can i clear this

Comment: Don't paste us screenshots of text.  Paste us the text.

Comment: You can fix whatever is wrong in your `.bash_profile`. Likely you don't want to source the file you're currently in, especially not on the same line as the `fi`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ruby. I have the tag removed.

Comment: just check the bash console it rbenv file that something went wrong with its syntax to update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `source <smth>` is on the same line as the `if` construct.

Open `.bash_profile` in any text editor, find line 22, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `fi` and then save the file.

Comment: Then fix the recursive sourcing.

Comment: how can i open .bash_profile

Comment: @AyazAhmadTarar, for example, with `open .bash_profile` or `nano .bash_profile`. This is to be run from the Terminal. If it gives you errors, try to prefix 'em with `sudo`: `sudo nano .bash_profile`, for example.